# Get specific files from a GIT remote branch

Tags: git

Is it possible to pull from a remote repository but only selectively take files from that remote that I'm interested in? I don't want to simply pull down the entire branch.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A "remote branch" is nothing more than a commit pointer and the affiliated pack data. Just `git fetch <remote>` and then if you want to view diffs between files on the remote and your local, you can do so with:

```
git diff <local_branch> <remote>/<remote_branch> -- <file>
```

This would in many cases be, for example, `git diff master origin/master -- <file>`. You could also see the commit differences with `git log`:

```
git log <local_branch>..<remote>/<remote_branch> -- <file>
```

so... `git log master..origin/master -- <file>`

Finally if you just want to checkout a particular version of a file from the remote (this wouldn't be ideal; much better to merge the remote branch with `git merge <remote>/<remote_branch>` or `git pull`), use:

```
git checkout <remote>/<remote_branch> -- <file>
```

Comment: I needed to first do `git fetch` before then doing something like `git checkout   origin/master -- *.{sh,rb,pl,R,py,php}`  to update just those local source files with fresher copies from the remote.  Even before any of that, I did `git stash` to not regret losing any possible local changes to outdated files never checked in.

Answer (score -1):

No you have to fetch the entire branch, but may choose to checkout specific files.

Comment: But what if I have files X,Y,Z,1,2,3 on my local, and X,Y,Z are in conflict from the server. Therefore, I want to view what is trying to come back from the remote branch and then choose to only take 1,2,3. Is that possible?

Comment: MeshMan - a pull is a fetch and merge - you don't want the merge part, just the information, so you can do a fetch instead.

Comment: What can I do with the data brought down from just a fetch?